# I don't seem to be able to suppress a code analysis message across a whole project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I want to suppress CA1303 across an entire project (or namespace would do, or whole solution would be even better - it's a Windows Forms project which will never be localised and is littered with autogenerated *blah.Text="so-n-so"*, I'm sure you've all been there).

Shouldn't I just be able to put something like:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters")]
```

into GlobalSuppressions.cs? No matter how I set (or omit) the arguments (Scope, Target etc.) on the SuppressMessage attribute I just can't seem to get it to work.

It's VS2012.

Anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, it seems that the answer is that it just can't be done, at least in VS2012. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/999c6753-c703-44eb-bf6a-c163f6c13a78/i-dont-seem-to-be-able-to-suppress-a-code-analysis-message-across-a-whole-project?forum=csharpgeneral) for the answer I got on the MSDN forum.